# My app assets are working only after one more push to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have simple Rails4 app on heroku.

I do some changes in assets like adding image or changing css file.
Run `git push heroku master` - it's updated with all changes except assets changes.

Now when I add new commit and push it to heroku, then assets changes from previous commit finally are working.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

1. Take a look into what Heroku thinks about assets:

   [assets pipeline on Heroku for rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)

   [assets pipeline on Heroku for rails 4](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline)
2. There is always an option to precompile assets manually:

   `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I had a similar issue.
precompile your assets before pushing:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

This might do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly caused by the sequence of git commands. Make sure you do the assets precompile before your git add so your updated assets are added to the committed change and then pushed.

```
$bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production 
$git add -A
$git commit -m "Important update"
$git merge branch_name ....
$git heroku push master
```